# Flutter disable bounce animation in list-view

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a list-view and I don't want to have this bounce animation at the end of the list. Is there any way I can disable that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's not bounce animation. That's splash effect is f I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes right that's it

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is like this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
      onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
        overscroll.disallowGlow();
      },
      child: ListView(),       //<-- your listview here
    );
}
```